# How to get CheckBox value from GridView when CheckBox selected

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have GridView filled automatically as

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvValues" runat="server" 
    OnRowDataBound="gvValues_RowDataBound" 
    OnPageIndexChanging="gvValues_PageIndexChanging" 
    <Columns>           
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="#">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# gvValues.PageSize*gvValues.PageIndex+ Container.DisplayIndex+1  %> 
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkProduct" runat="server" CssClass="chkProduct"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="online" meta:resourcekey="Online">
            <ItemTemplate > 
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkProductonline" runat="server"  OnCheckedChanged ="chkProductonline_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

What I need is when I click on the `chkProductonline` checkbox, to fire an event and get the `chkProductonline` and `chkProducton` values. I have tried this but it always gives me null.

```
protected void chkProductonline_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var chkProductonline = FindControl("chkProductonline") as CheckBox;
    // bool ischeck = chkProductonline.Checked;

    var chkProduct = gvValues.FindControl("chkProduct") as CheckBox;
}
```

I can't loop the GridView. I need to do this one-by-one. Is there another way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
protected void chkProductonline_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox chkProductonline = sender as CheckBox;
    ...

    CheckBox chkProduct = chkProductionLine.NamingContainer.FindControl("chkProduct") as CheckBox;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call FindControl on a specific row. You will not be able to call it on the entire GridView because there exists repeating content (i.e. multiple chkProductionlines and chkProducts). A row knows of *its* checkboxes, and not of the others.

So what you can do is first get the CheckBox that called the event (your sender parameter, chkProductionline) and use its [NamingContainer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.namingcontainer(v=vs.110).aspx). Since it is contained in a GridView row, cast the row as such as use it to find the other controls you may need.

```
protected void chkProductonline_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox chkProductionline = (CheckBox)sender;
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)chkProductionline.NamingContainer;

    CheckBox chkProduct = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkProduct");
}
```